# How to properly divide business and data layer in a Spring Boot Rest Interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working with Spring Boot for quite some time now but have surprinsingly not encountered this type of problem before.

Given the following Code example:

**Parent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Parent")
@Cacheable(true)
@OptimisticLocking(type= OptimisticLockType.VERSION)
@DynamicUpdate

public class Parent implements Serializable {

   private Long id;
   private Child child;

   @Id
   public Long getId() {
     return this.id;
   }

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "child")
   public Child getChild(){
     return this.child;
   }
}
```

**Child**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Child")
@Cacheable(true)
@OptimisticLocking(type= OptimisticLockType.VERSION)
@DynamicUpdate

public class Child implements Serializable {

   private Long id;
   private String name;

   @Id
   public Long getId() {
     return this.id;
   }

   public String getName() {
     return this.name;
   }
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class RestController {

@Autowired
private ParentRepository parentRepository;


@RequestMapping(value="/data/parent/{parentid}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Optional<Parent> getParent(@PathVariable("parentid") Long parentId){
   return parentRepository.findById(parentId);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/data/parent", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Parent addParent(@RequestBody Parent parent) {
   return parentRepository.save(parent);   
}
```

The above code works fine and as expected when executing the GET method. A result would look something like:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "child": {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Jesus"
}
}
```

However, The way I need to use the POST method is to pass only the foreign key of the children that I want to connect to my parent. I do not want to create a whole Child Object, serialize it into JSON and add it to the request body. Meaning I want to be able to POST a Parent object with a JSON like this:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "child":1
}
```

and let the Rest Interface to the job of fetching my Child object.

I was able to find a way to achieve this by adding another variable

```
@Transient
Long childId;
```

to my Parent object and then in the controller, GET the corresponding Child object first and add it to the Parent before persisting.

However, I am quite certain that this is not a good way to solve this problem and that the solution will include dividing my data model into two seperate layers. Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to find out how to do this exactly.

I am thankful for any advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should divide your business model by layers : `DTO` (used for data exchanging with your REST clients) and `Entities` (for database operations).

With that seperation you have more flexibility and can `POST` what you want without messing your entities with stuff like `@JsonIgnore` or `@Transient`.

You will have something like:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/data/parent")
public ParentDTO addParent(@RequestBody LightParentDTO parentDTO) {
   return service.save(parentDTO);   
}
```

and

```
class LightParentDTO {
  long parentId;
  long childId;
}
```

Note that I introduce a `service.save(...)`, there you can do all your `DTO` to `Entity` conversion operations.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, what you need to do is use the @jsonignore annotation
Try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Parent")
@Cacheable(true)
@OptimisticLocking(type= OptimisticLockType.VERSION)
@DynamicUpdate

public class Parent implements Serializable {

   private Long id;
   @JsonIgnore     <========================================================
   private Child child;

   @Id
   public Long getId() {
     return this.id;
   }

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "child")
   public Child getChild(){
     return this.child;
   }
}
```

let me know if it works